# ObservableCollection inside a async Task

Tags: c#, mvvm, task-parallel-library

I have this strange behaviour of a ObservableCollection inside a task.

This works OK:

```
    private string status;
    public string Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set { SetField<string>(ref status, value); }
    }

    public void AddRandomTask()
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Randomizer.Instance.LongRandAsync (new MainViewModelObserver(this));
                });

                t.ContinueWith(m => 
                    {
                        string s = "done: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                        Status = s;
                    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

                Tasks.Add(t);       

                Msg.Add("Task is added");
            }
```

This fails with 2 excepions:

in the constructor

```
Msg = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

and further:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Msg { get; private set; }

public void AddRandomTask()
        {
            Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Randomizer.Instance.LongRandAsync(new MainViewModelObserver(this));
            });

            t.ContinueWith(m => 
                {
                    string s = "done: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                    this.Msg.Add(s);
                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            Tasks.Add(t);       

            Msg.Add("Task is added");
        }
```

What am I missing, and why is a string property different from a ObservableCollection?

Edit: Exceptions:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Are those actually uncaught exceptions? They just look like debugger notifications of exceptions that could be caught by the framework. Also the exception message would be helpful.

Comment: Those aren't the exceptions.  Any exceptions would have been thrown in your code and would have caused your application to exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on without a minimal, reproducible example; but I suspect the problem is that your code is changing an observable collection that is data-bound to a UI element.

As a general rule, I always treat my ViewModel properties (including observable collections) as though they have UI affinity.

> why is a string property different from a ObservableCollection?

I assume by this you mean that you found you could change a string property from a background thread and have it work, while changing an `ObservableCollection` from a background thread would throw an exception. Well, WPF tries to make things easy for you by doing some automatic thread marshaling behind the scenes for simple properties. And the latest version [also supports some level of this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization(v=vs.110).aspx) for collections, too.

But I recommend you don't use it. For one thing, WPF is the only XAML platform AFAIK that supports this. Windows Store, Universal apps, Xamarin Forms, ... No one else does, even for simple properties. Also, keeping your UI (and the logical representation of your UI - your ViewModel) separate from your background processing code will keep your code more portable, as well as encouraging separation of concerns and just plain cleaner and simpler.

So, IMO the best approach is just to not update ViewModels from background threads. In your case, it looks like the `Task.Run` is superfluous anyway, so this turns out to be a relatively easy fix:

```
public void AddRandomTask()
{
  Task t = ProcessAsync();
  Tasks.Add(t);       
  Msg.Add("Task is added");
}

private async Task ProcessAsync()
{
  await Randomizer.Instance.LongRandAsync(new MainViewModelObserver(this));
  string s = "done: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
  this.Msg.Add(s);
}
```

Also note the use of a separate `async` method, which removes the need for an explicit `ConfigureAwait` / `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Thanks!. I had a construct like this in the first place. But then I wanted to cancel ProcessAsync, and ended up with the code posted in the question. Any thoughts on this? 
Will the methods of the observer MainViewModelObserver also be called on the UI thread?

Comment: I treat all ViewModels as UI-affinated. So all property access and method calls must be done from the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

It's not failing nor it is a bug, it's a feature.

> **Does a first chance exception mean there is a problem in my code?**
>
> First chance exception messages most often do not mean there is a
> problem in the code. For applications / components which handle
> exceptions gracefully, first chance exception messages let the
> developer know that an exceptional situation was encountered and was
> handled.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx